# Vue JS how to change <GoogleLogin /> component text

Tags: vuejs3

I have incorporated the `vue3-google-oauth2` package into my Vue.js project to enable Google OAuth. I'm looking to modify the button text from 'Sign in with Google' to 'Sign up with Google' in my code. Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="loggedIn">
      <button @click="logout" id="signout_button">logout</button>
      <h3>The name is: {{ user.name }}</h3>
      <h3>The email is: {{ user.email }}</h3>
      <img :src="user.picture" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <GoogleLogin :callback="callback" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { decodeCredential, googleLogout } from 'vue3-google-login'
let user = null
let loggedIn = ref(false)

const callback = (response) => {
  console.log('logged in')
  loggedIn.value = true
  console.log(response)
  user = decodeCredential(response.credential)
  console.log(user)
}

function logout() {
  googleLogout()
  loggedIn.value = false
  user = null
  callback.value = null
}

</script>
```

[image]

any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<GoogleLogin>` component accepts a prop called [buttonConfig](https://devbaji.github.io/vue3-google-login/#plugin-options-and-googlelogin-component-props)

One of the available button config properties is [`text`](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#GsiButtonConfiguration)

The [text value](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#text) "signup_with" will change the button text to "Sign up with Google"

```html
<GoogleLogin :callback="callback" :button-config="{ text: 'signup_with' }" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! How did you search for sources or documentation like those